# Selenium Python Element Click Intercepted

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

I'm trying to run a test in Selenium Webdriver Python, but I got an error saying as on the screenshot:

[image]

this is the xpath for the register button: `//button[@class='tutor-btn tutor-btn-primary']`

What I tried so far:

```
setup.find_element("xpath", "//button[@class='tutor-btn tutor-btn-primary']").click()
```

and

```
setup.find_element("xpath", "//button[@type='submit' and (contains(@class,'tutor-btn tutor-btn-primary')) and(contains(text(),'Register'))]").click()
```

but none works, any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Element click intercepted` indicates that some other element is obstructing selenium to perform the `click()` on the desired element.

And that obstructing element is Accept Cookies window.

[image]

As soon as you open the application, just add below line and get rid of the cookies window. It should be fine:

```
driver.get("https://langsungkerja.id/registration/")
driver.maximize_window()
# below line will accept cookies
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept All']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

setup.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.tutor-btn.tutor-btn-primary').click()
```

[update]

Here is another unique way where you don't even need to click on the "Accept All" button.

```
driver.get("https://langsungkerja.id/registration/")

driver.add_cookie({"name": "cookieyes-consent", "value": "consent:yes,action:yes"})
driver.refresh()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.tutor-btn.tutor-btn-primary').click()
time.sleep(1)
```

I hope you'll like it

Comment: Tried this just now but I got another error saying: ```NameError: name 'By' is not defined```

Comment: @jyra, I updated the code, you need to import it

Comment: still got the same error ```Element Click Intercepted```

Comment: @jyra,  can you share the URL which you're trying if it's public to get you the help

Comment: sure, it's this web https://langsungkerja.id/registration/

Comment: @jyra, you can see above in the updated code the alternate way to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this function, it needs to get element object.

```
def click_element(self, element):
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

First step here is to check if the element you're trying to click is overlayed by anything. Especially labels love to cover buttons/radios. In that case you need to click the label instead of the button/radio/etc.

While generally not recommended for testing purposes it's absolutely legit for automation purposes to circumvent things that would block a click through javascript or jquery scripts.

One such example was already posted by piscoony, another one would be something like:

```
def click_js(driver, dom_class):
    driver.execute_script("$('#" + str(dom_class) + "').click()")
```

However, i do not see any labels or other obvious elements overlaying the button. Could you please post what element would block the click? It's cut off in the screenshot.

Something you might also try is look for temporary overlays. I run into seethrough overlays blocking elements while f.e. ajax is active occasionally, i can only guess what those are used for, they seem janky but occur here and there. They  often trigger this error for me is to check if those are active with something like

```
def visibility_check(driver, dom_class):
    driver.execute_script("return $('." + dom_class + ":visible').length")
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me. My page doesn't load fully when I log in to the site, with the code below it scrolls to the bottom for the elements that will receive the click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from time import sleep 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

 chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : r"C:\Users\adm\OneDrive\\"} #change download folder
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
browser.get("url")
sleep (2)

WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "filter")))
view_checkSicom = browser.find_element(By.ID, "filter")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", view_checkSicom)
Check_sicom = browser.find_element(By.ID, "filter")
Check_sicom.click()
```